# Integrating Bugzilla with CVS/SVN

Tags: svn, version-control, integration, cvs, bugzilla

I am trying to integrate Bugzilla with CVS/SVN. So far, I have come across tools such as CVSZilla and ScmBug.
I need to be able to parse through comments in CVS/SVN, append those comments to the bug report and modify the status of the bug in Bugzilla.

My question : Should I use ScmBug or write hooks for CVS/SVN and a script that will modify the Bugzilla db directly ?

If I do choose to write my own scripts, is it recommended to append comments and change status of bugs by updating Bugzilla's db.

Please help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach I took was to use the Bugzilla JSON API to modify the bug during the subversion commit hook. http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.0/en/html/api/Bugzilla/WebService/Server/JSONRPC.html

I wouldn't modify the db directly.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Will explore this possibility.

Comment: Thank you very much. We have decided to adopt this approach.